# Is there an app that lets me add margins to photos to make them square without cropping them?

Tags: image-processing, photography, productivity, instagram

I was traveling and I want to post 10 pictures from this trip on Instagram. However, these pictures are all of different sizes. Some are landscape, others are portrait, and others are custom. If I upload them just like this to Instagram, the first picture will dictate the orientation of the other pics, which will be cropped to fit. In order to prevent important aspects of the photos to be cropped out, I would like to process a batch of 10 pictures and add black margins to them where necessary make them square without cropping anything out. Is there any free/freemium iOS app where I can do this quickly?

Comment: Without cropping they will look so ugly that you immediately delete them. Example: original https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELNOD.jpg Square: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeqjN.jpg

Comment: Original:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyk0m.png Squared: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTwNO.png 
Original: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPDwd.jpg
Squared: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG5zt.jpg So really, no, **please no**. Nobody wants to see that.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my original question. I just updated it. By "turning them into squares without cropping" I meant adding margins to them where necessary, not just distorting the image to fit in a square.